# parse const char* argv[]

Tags: objective-c

**Code:-**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    int main(int argc, const char* argv[]){
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        char* charString = argv[1];

    printf("%s", charString);


        [pool drain];
        return 0;
    }
```

**Problem:-**

But the above line is printing null, how to get the array of integers;

Comment: You have two questions here 1. code problem 2. algorithm problem. You should solve both things separately. The question as it stands is too broad ("write this assignment for me").

Comment: Your "input" and "output" example does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

`argv[0]` is the name of your program. If you want to read your parameters, start by reading `argv[1]`. Of course, you should also check that there are actually some parameters using `argc > 1`.

Or you could use `[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments]`

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]){
    @autoreleasepool {
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
            NSString *stringArgument = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", argv[i]];
            NSLog(@"%@", stringArgument);
            NSLog(@"Integer value: %i", [stringArgument intValue]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

or

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]){
    @autoreleasepool {
        for (NSString *argument in [NSProcessInfo processInfo].arguments) {
            NSLog(@"%@", argument);
            NSLog(@"Integer value: %i", [argument intValue]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Arguments: `10 20`

Output:

> ObjcTest[65709:1964435] /Projects/ObjcTest/Build/Products/Debug/ObjcTest
>   ObjcTest[65709:1964435] Integer value: 0
>   ObjcTest[65709:1964435] 10
>   ObjcTest[65709:1964435] Integer value: 10
>   ObjcTest[65709:1964435] 20
>   ObjcTest[65709:1964435] Integer value: 20

Note the first argument cannot be converted to an integer therefore the printed value is `0`.